# WPF - How can I access to elements in different tabs that are defined in separated XAMLs?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, tabs

Well, the situation is this: I have a WPF project that contains a TabControl with 2 TabItems. One tab contains just a TextBlock, and the other one has a TextBox and a button. What I want to achieve is that when pressing the button, the text inside the TextBox of the second tab appears in the TextBlock of the first tab.

It should be an easy duty, but I'm stuck because I have each tab designed in a separated XAML (and I need to keep it that way), and I have this MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="TabsUserControl.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabsUserControl"
    x:Name="root"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <TabControl Name="tabCtrl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="210" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="366" Margin="89,47,0,0">
        <local:UserTabControl1 Name="tab1"/>
        <local:UserTabControl2 Name="tab2"/>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

All the elements have an assigned name, so how can I access to them to write the methods in the .cs file of the XAML for the second tab?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a binding to the text-property of each textbox, with two-way-mode. If the button is pressed: set the value of the first propert to the second.

The properties look like:

```
private string text1;
public string Text1
{
get{return this.text1;}
set{
this.text1 = value;
OnPropertyChanged("Text1");}
}

private string text2;
public string Text2
{
get{return this.text2;}
set{
this.text2 = value;
OnPropertyChanged("Text2");}
}
```

In the Click-Event (or ExecuteCommand) of your button you just have to do:

```
Text1 = Text2;
```

That's it

Answer (score 0):

Since you most definitly want those user controls decoupled from each other I would use a seperate Messaging class for DataExchange. Such a class is already available in the MVVM Light Toolkit. One UC can publish information the other can receive.

Otherwise it's possible to let your Window make the syncronisation via binding if your user control with the text box provides the Text as a Dependency Property.